# Is there any way to write DI without autoface with Linq / Refraction in .net core web api?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0, autofac, asp.net-core-webapi

I am used to working with AutoFace for DI, I have one of my application where I use Autoface for DI in asp.net MVC as mentioned below.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(BankRepository).Assembly)
.Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
.AsImplementedInterfaces()
.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Now I am preparing a new application in asp.net core for web Api.

I came to know that .net core comes with built-in DI feature. 
So that I can register my dependencies like following way.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddDbContext<DbEntities>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbEntities")));


            services.AddScoped<ISizeRepository, SizeRepository>(); 
            //But the prob is that I have to specify each repository & it's implemenation here                
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            services.AddScoped<IDatabaseFactory, DatabaseFactory>();                             

        }
```

Issue: 
1. There might be 100+ repository, so it will be lengthy code just for DI registration.
2. Every time, for new repository, I have to add an entry to this portion, which is kind of overhead.

Is there any way in asp.net core to do the dependency registration the way Autofac provide using Linq & Refraction.

Comment: It would be better to use a factory pattern to obtain your repository instances. Then, you need only inject your factory. Much more pragmatic.

Comment: @ChrisPratt can you share some ref. links which I can review & understand for practical implementation.

Comment: The built-in DI container does not contain any Batch-Registration features (a.k.a. assembly scanning). I would advise sticking with Autofac as this is a very mature DI container.

Comment: Your repositories should live inside of your UnitOfWork. So there should be no need to even register your repositories